# NodeJS: Unable to push new data onto array

Tags: arrays, node.js, request, return, cheerio

I am currently building an web service using an external API and crawling data using Cheerio. I was able to get the data from Cheerio and trying to push a new variable from the crawl to the item data (article). I've tried item.push({"new content":new content here});, as well as return (variable name), but I am unable to append the new variable to the field image_url. I have no problems with Cheerio and the output of the overall service.

How would go about appending the content variable?

```
request("<API URL HERE>", function(error, response, body) {
 var myObject = JSON.parse(body);
 var listing = myObject.items; 

 arr = listing.map(function(item) { 

   var url = item.url;
   //get individual images for articles based on URL
   update =  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
       if (!error) {
         var $ = cheerio.load(body) 
         content = $('.post-body').find('img').attr('src');
         return content; 

      }
      else {
        console.log("We’ve encountered an error: " + error);
      }
   });

   //return format for each article 
   return { 
      "title": item.title, 
      "subtitle": item.content.substr(0,100), 
      "image_url": update.content,
       "buttons":
          [{
              "type":"web_url",
              "url":item.url,
              "title":"View Item"
            }]

     };
 });

 res.send({
  "messages": [
   {
     "attachment":{
     "type":"template",
     "payload":{
       "template_type":"generic",
       "elements": arr
      }
   }
  }
 ]
 })
});
```

Comment: do the push inside `request` as you are asking data from some external source and the data will be available in future time.

Comment: Since you're dealing with asyncronous events, when you're doing the `push` the data hasn't arrived yet. You should use a [Promise](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises)

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with External APIs databases etc,  the code becomes asynchronous . This means that by the time you send the update request , variable content will be undefined because the response didn't come back yet . Node provides lots of ways to deal with asynchronous code . A cool way is promises . If you don't know about promises , just read this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

What you should do is something like this :

```
  var url = item.url;
   //get individual images for articles based on URL
  const update = () => {
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => { 
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
     if (!error) {
       var $ = cheerio.load(body) 
      content = $('.post-body').find('img').attr('src');
      resolve(content); 

    }
    else {
      reject(error)
    }
  });
 }
})
```